# What DEMs does QGIS support?

Tags: qgis, dem

I am working on QGIS rasters.

What DEM file formats are supported by QGIS?

I know that QGIS can read the GDAL supported formats but not what the GDAL supported formats are.

I do not know whether QGIS supports all the DEMs supported by ArcGIS Desktop.

Answer (score 6):

`Settings -> Options ->GDAL` gives you a reliable list what is possible with **your** installed QGIS version.

It might well be that some QGIS versions on some platforms do not support everything that is available in GDAL sources.

Answer (score 3):

All the GDAL formats are here http://www.gdal.org/formats_list.html.  A quick [web search](http://letmegooglethat.com/?q=gdal%20supported%20format) will give you what you need

Answer (score 1):

most of the argis raster formats are supported by gdal/qgis as well. especially looking at the common ones like Tiff, bigtiff, jpg, png, gif and many more. have a look on the [comparison sheat](http://dragons8mycat.wordpress.com/2013/08/07/gis-software-comparison-matrix-a-work-in-progress/) of nicholas duggan created. maybe you will find more answers there.